# Testing javascript inside IIFE

Tags: javascript, jasmine, iife

My team leader wants me to wrap my js code inside an IIFE immediatly-invoked function expression.  I can't figure out how to spyOn in my jasmine spec file.

How would I spyOn the follow:

```
(function(){
function_1(){...}
function_2(){...}
});
```

`spyOn(window,'function_1')` doesn't work.
Passing window into the IIFE doesn't work.

Trying both `(x=function()...` and `(function x() ...` then `spyOn(x,'function_1')` doesn't work either.

I couldn't find anything on-line about this.

Comment: Here's a solution to solve this without spyOn()

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27561337/solution-to-testing-angularjs-inside-an-iife

Answer (score 1):

@user29998, if you can expose those functions to test via a `return` block, you can do something as found on this jsbin link: http://jsbin.com/yohux/1/edit?js,console

[image]

Comment: I should have clarified this more in my question (will make an edit). I want to run the test from an external file (jasmine spec file). I can't this to work for me on the external jasmine spec file.

Comment: Just like how a `var i` inside a _function_ isn't available outside that function, the contents of an _IIFE_ are the same. If you can't edit the source/your own copy of the source then you won't be able to view these internals. That said, if you're able to access the source via code without interpreting then you could always modify it on-the-fly before it's invoked. This is unlikely if your domain is not included by _CORS_.

Comment: the nature of the IIFE is to encapsulate these variables/functions. If they are not exposed in any way and are not supposed to be, they essentially can not be tested by an external test runner.

I would ask your team leader how they practically do this so they can show you. Post up their answer here