# Testing JS from outside a closure

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, iife

I have an application that is defined in an IIFE like so:

```
(function () {
  'use strict'

  function xxx () {
    ...
  }

  function yyy () {
    ...
  }
)());
```

This common pattern avoids clobbering the global object etc, but I need to get some unit-testing in.  I'm currently looking at [Jasmine 2.0](http://jasmine.github.io/2.0/introduction.html), however my objects (all defined inside that IIFE) aren't available in my test spec files - every reference is (understandably) undefined.

### My Question:

How do people usually go about testing (with Jasmine or anything else) a Javascript application that is defined this way?

Comment: Using modules. Check out Browserify.

Comment: You can return an object containing all the functions from the IIFE for the sake of tests. Well yea, you'll end up with a single object in global scope.

Comment: Possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24066796/testing-javascript-inside-iife

Comment: Check out the 'revealing module pattern'