# How to you test an angularjs module defined inside an IIFE with jasmine?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, unit-testing, jasmine, iife

how do I test this module on jasmine ? 
The problem is that it's very difficult to test the `$controller` because the function is hidden  inside a closure, it’s very difficult to test them.

In other words, given the module definition below, writing a unit test for MainCtrl seems impossible.

```
(function () {

    'use strict';

    angular.module('app', []);

    function MainCtrl() {
      var mc = this;
      mc.obj = {
        val : 50  
      };
    }

    angular.module('app').controller('MainCtrl', MainCtrl);

} () );
```

and the "typical" jasmine test

```
describe('app', function(){

  beforeEach(module('app'));

  it('should create an objet with val 50', inject(function(_$controller_) {
    var scope = {},
        ctrl = _$controller_('MainCtrl', {$scope:scope});

    expect(scope.obj.val).toBe(50); // returns Expected undefined to be 50.
  }));

});
```

When angular inject the `_$controller_` service inside the jasmine test function, The instance of the controller created returns with an undefined $scope.

So How can you test it?

My search on StackOverflow for a solution to this problem, didn't give me the answer I was looking for so I implemented one of my own.

Comment: Answering your own question is allowed, but currently I think the question is unclear and makes it less useful. Can you rephrase this as a clear, concise question (see [ask])?  Right now, it's little more than a block of code with no explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be tested with jasmine simply by doing this :

```
describe('app', function () {

    var $controller;

    beforeEach(function () {

        module('app');

        inject(function (_$controller_) {

            $controller = _$controller_('MainCtrl');

        });
    });

    //-- spec - test controller

    describe('Controller : MainCtrl', function () {

        it('should create an object with val 50', function () {

            expect($controller.obj.val).toBe(50);

        });
    });

});
```

here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jfabfab/g3a6hxmx/) for it

Hope it helps !

Comment: @AndrewT. yes, that's what I meant. Thank you for the clarification

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here

`var scope = {},
        ctrl = _$controller_('MainCtrl', {$scope:scope});`

You're importing undefined scope. You need to do something like this:

1. Inject `$rootScope` :
   `inject(function (_$controller_, _$rootScope_)`
2. Construct new scope: 
   `var scope = $rootScope.$new();`
3. Build controller:
   `var ctrl = _$controller_('MainCtrl', {$scope: scope});`

Comment: did you mean:  step 2. var scope = _$rootScope_.$new() ? (you missed the hyphen)